# How to send email listed in Views?

Tags: views, webforms

I want to send emails listed in [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views). The email column is collected from data submission of anonymous users (without login). The form is created using [webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform).

The table looks like this:

```
Name     |  email address
---------------------------
Name one | emailone@tod.ten
Name two | emailtwo@tof.fen
```

I have tried [Views Send](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_send) module without any success as reported in the issue about "[Can't use email collected from a webform submission field](https://www.drupal.org/node/2622526)".

How can I send email to all emails in the column?

or anyone can suggest another method.

Comment: Are you using an email field type for the column? https://www.drupal.org/project/email

Comment: The data submission use webform. The component type for the email is already email type. I send the confirmation to the submitter using the submitted email data. Things correct in the webform. In Views, the column generated from webform submission > select node > select component data > data type. The data type available only "string" and "number", there is no "email". I have also email field module installed.

Comment: Does the solution you're looking for really HAVE to use the Views module, or would you be interested in an alternative solution (module) which doesn't use/require Views? If so please edit (expand) your question to somehow indicate that (and let me know you edited your question via a short extra comment around here).

Comment: Any method that can be the solution of the objective will be considered. So far what I always use to collect data from webform submission is Views.